# How do i set up button of deploy and abort in mail

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have 4stages. On the completion of 3rd stage i should get an mail notification on my mail where i should get 2 options of abort/deploy. In the mail itself if i click on deploy the job should be triggered and if i abort in the mail then the job should be aborted.

Comment: What have you tried? How was that not sufficient?

Comment: I have tried. But what happens is i get an link to my mail and when i click on the link it directs me to Jenkins UI. Where my job is paused and when i click on it i get 2options i.e abort or deploy. The job proceeds further as per my selection. But the requirements are bit different. The mail which i want to trigger i don't want that user to view or have access to my Jenkins UI. So the mail which he receives should have a attached build log along with 2 options (abort/deploy). In mail whatever he chose the pipeline should proceed accordingly

Comment: That doesn't sound very secure. If you're the person in charge of this pipeline I would push back against that requirement. If you can't do that, it's possible that you can embed the "Proceed" and "Abort" button into the mail itself, but it will be nontrivial. The best solution to this seems to be to not allow this workflow.

Comment: I completely agree. But as of now this what the requirements are. Because the person who will receive the mail should able to see the build log only and should get 2 options in the mail itself where he can either chose to deploy or to abort. There is whole lot things in the backend. So the person in charge who will get the mail would be aware what is going to happen in the job. But all we want is not to have him go to our Jenkins UI and see the job builds. He should only be able to do it in mail

Comment: Any way how can i do it @Adam Smith??